# how to test my windows 8 application

Tags: android, ios5, windows-8

I am planing to develop a widows 8 based app using HTML5. I do not own any windows phone/tablet.

Has Microsoft/or any third party come out with an app that allows me to test the sensors on iOS/Android based devices?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8, there is a simulator which allows you to simulate the functionality of a tablet: touch, orientation (so you can simulate rotating a tablet into portrait mode), different resolutions/screen sizes, and location.  But to develop using this, you have to be running Windows 8 as an operating system.

There is not support from Microsoft for testing on iOS/Android devices.  However, there are a few third parties who have built game creation software (like [GameSalad](http://gamesalad.com/) or [Scirra's Construct 2](http://scirra.com)) which allows you to build a game and then export it as a Windows 8 app (and an iOS app and an Android app, etc.).  It's possible that you can use these even if you aren't running Windows 8 as your operating system.

Comment: I am doing this as a college project. So will need program develop my app and will then need to demonstrate it in class. But since there are no Win8 devices in market yet, I am confused whether I should go ahead with Win8 platform.

Comment: Parin, any machine that can run Windows 7 can also run Windows 8 - they are the same in terms of hardware requirements.  So you don't have to wait on Windows 8 optimized machines, although there are some available already, like the Samsung Series 7 Slate.  http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/tablet-pcs/XE700T1A-A03US

Comment: Also, check out DreamSpark if you're a student.  You can get access to free software and registration to the Windows Store.  You can get started with Windows 8 development using this guide: https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Windows-8-App-Development.aspx